# Laravel @parent not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im new to laravel and trying to create a template for my app, im using @parent as shown here 'https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#introduction' but it doesnt seem to work, please check the code below, what am i doing wrong?

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }} @yield('title')</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        @section('heading')
        <h1>Testing</h1>
        @endsection

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light navbar-laravel">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                            </li>
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

i have a section('heading') in this file.
now i have another view register.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title','Testing')

@section('heading')
    @parent
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" aria-label="{{ __('Register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Name') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('name') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('name'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('name') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

now i am extending this file and using @parent so the heading section is loaded from parent view, but it is not working, any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: that happens when the doctor does not listen to patient problem completely, just like u didn't read the complete post, anyway I'd rather discuss the issue I asked than answer someone who doesn't have anything better to do, bye

Comment: I did read the complete post, and didn't find what is the problem. Instead I found "is not working" twice. So now I can assume that you get an actual error message, that you have duplicated content, that you don't get the content at all... many ways of "is not working", but yet instead of trying to explain better to the same people you're asking for help, you complain, so I'll keep the answers and time to find them to myself, thanks and bye

Comment: I am struggling in Laravel 5.8 with the difference between `@endsection` and `@show` and whether I need `@parent` or not and I have been using Laravel since version 4 for 5 years. I found this question really helpful and Tân Nguyễn's answer brought me the insight I needed. The documentation is good, but sometimes I need a StackExchange answer to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

The @endsection directive will only define a section while  @show will define and immediately yield the section.
In app.blade you use

```
@section('heading')
    <h1>Testing</h1>
@show
```

and in register.blade you can use

```
@section('heading')
    @parent
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2):

In the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#template-inheritance) they are using `@show` rather than `@endsection`. Did you try this?

Comment: it works after i replace it with @show, but it shows all the time, i only wanted to show this section on some pages, now i think i misunderstood this directive, it is just to extend the section, not when i want to show it conditionally on some pages

Comment: Exactly, a section can be empty if you don't want to show anything by default, but still need to ability to extend it.

Comment: This little exchange also helped me finally get the "Eureka" moment with `@endsection`, `@show` and `@parent`.